# Logistic regression model built on under sampled data set

Tags: regression, logistic, survey-sampling

I built a logistic regression model based on under sampled data set. Do I need to apply the model on the whole data set and report the performance based on whole data set? I heard people talking about correct back. What does "correct back" mean?

Thanks!

-NaNaN

Comment: Can you define what you mean undersampled? Do you mean you have a small sample size? Was it a retrospective design with "cases" matched to "controls" in a 1:10 or 1:1 fashion?

Comment: By under sampling I mean I choose 40% of the data from class 1 and 100% data from class 2. So the weights assigned to class 1 is 2.5 and weights assigned to class 1 is 1.

Comment: is your "class 1" and "class 2" an outcome or an exposure in this model?

Comment: class 1 and class 2 are class labels

Comment: That is not helpful, since there is ambiguous use of terminology here between machine learning and statistics. If we use the terminology "X" and "Y", is what you are calling the "class" the X or the Y?